# Round integer variable into x amount of digits

Tags: php

I have:

```
$int = 11487171;
```

I want to round it to the first 3 digits, making it `115`. What's the PHP function to do this? Apologies for entry level question.

Comment: Since it's an integer, rounding would mean `11500000`. You are imagining some sort of truncation logic which I don't fully understand...

Comment: I changed his question because it's obvious that he is talking about rounding or truncation here, but if I changed it too much feel free to change it back.

Comment: You could do: `round(11487171 / 100000);`

Comment: @user3483203 Now it makes sense at least, yeah...

Comment: @Henrik you have two answers to your question, why don't you accept or leave a  comment. They did that for more reputation in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If the number has 3 or less digits, just output it as, else divide it by 10^(digits-3) and round the result.

Could be easily done with `strlen`, and `round`.

```
$len = strlen($int);
if ($len <= 3) {
    echo $int;
} else {
    echo round($int / pow(10, $len - 3), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it using [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$digit = 11487171;

function makeit($digit){
  return $digit? substr($digit, 3, 1)>=5? 
    substr($digit, 0, 3)+1:substr($digit, 0, 3): 
      substr($digit, 0, 3);
}

echo makeit($digit);//print 115
```